# mysql SELECT with WHERE and AND returns some out of range results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to return rows in a MySQL database where the minimum elevation (minele) of a plant is less than or equal to a stated minimum and the maximum elevation (maxele) is greater than or equal to a stated maximum. In other words, the plant can be found within the tested range of elevation.

An example query is

```
SELECT * FROM `myflowers` 
WHERE minele <= 8001 AND maxele >= 8250 
ORDER BY color, sfamily, cname";
```

The problem is that some of the returned rows do not include elevations within the test range. For instance, for the above query, although most of the returned rows meet the select conditions, a row may be returned with values of minele = 2000 and maxele = 5000. This plant is found at elevations lower than searched for in the above query.

How do I modify my query to eliminate rows that do not meet the conditions of the query? I don't see a problem with the elevation data in the database (datatype int).

Comment: What is your table structure?
`SHOW CREATE TABLE myflowers;`

Comment: Your logic is backwards. From what it sounds like, you want where the minele is greater than 8001 and the maxele is less than 8250. Switch your brackets around.

Comment: I suspect your logic is not the one you need (now you're basically finding flowers with large ranges) but what you describe does not look possible. Are you sure this is the actual query you are running? Are you connecting to the correct database instance?

Comment: Most plants grow at elevation ranges wider than the narrow tested range. I want plants whose range of growth elevations includes elevations in the tested range but not to the exclusion of growing at ranges outside the tested range. The example plant's maximum elevation is less than the tested range (not in the tested range) but was still included in the data set.

Comment: Alvaro, yes this is the actual query. There is only one table in the database. Most of the results of the query are correct (plants with wide ranges of elevation of growth but including elevations in the tested range) but includes some plants which do not grow at the tested range of elevation.

Comment: @briang Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data that produces the incorrect result? The only way I could see this happening is if you wrote `OR` instead of `AND`. BTW, when you want to send a comment to someone, put `@` before their name so they'll be notified. There's auto-completion with TAB that helps with spelling.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63cdc/1/0 (Would you please check, whether your code is correct or not)

Comment: @LoHertel, your code is working as I would expect and want. I suspect I may miss a few plants who do grow in a narrow range totally within the tested range. However, most plants grow in several thousand foot ranges. However, my datasets would also include a flower like your flower6 which you do not get in your dataset..

Comment: @LoHertel, is adding a link to a webpage on my website that shows these results permissible on stackoverflow and with no security issues?

Comment: Thank you to those who responded to my problem. I found the issue was in the 'echo' section where I was not advancing the coding for each $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result4501) (i.e. the 4501) statement. Problem solved, I think.